# why java/android allows bitwise & between a boolean variable and a String

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I am allowed to do a bitwise & between a boolean variable and a String.
There is no compilation error!

What would the result? How does it work.
As per my understanding, it shall not allow the bitwise operation of this type.
Is it a bug or bitwise feature thinks only interms of bit and dont care about type?

Comment: Have you tried anything out to see of your hypothesis is true or not?

Comment: Show some code please! That's impossible!

Comment: I confused it little bit I guess, its between boolean and boolean. boolean test = true; String test1 = "hello";                       if(test & test1!=0) { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to `bitwise &` characters, but not Strings. Exapmle:

```
public class BitwiseTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(2));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1&2));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1&'2'));
  }
}
```

prints ...

```
0
1
10
11
110011
```

whereas this does not compile:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1&"my String"));
```

compiler output:

```
$ javac BitwiseTest.java 
BitwiseTest.java:10: operator & cannot be applied to int,java.lang.String
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1&"my String"));
                                           ^
1 error
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It answers my question. I will check it out for Boolean myself.

Comment: For boolean it is pretty simple: true evaluates to 1, false to 0. But still it's confusing...

Comment: I got it. Its short circuit and non-short circuit operations.. Thanks allot.